# What happend if I configure a queue size limit in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash

I'd like to find a way to limit the quantity of messages in a queue using rabbitmq.
I read this article http://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html where it say the following:

> *Configuring the "x-max-length" parameter Messages will be dropped or dead-lettered from the front of the queue to make room for new
>   messages once the limit is reached.*

My question is what happen with the dropped messages? We have logstash as publishers but we don't want to lose some data.

I hope to have explained clearly.

Regards.

Mijhael.

Answer (score 4):

As [official RabbitMQ doc on Queue Length Limit](http://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html) says:

> Messages will be dropped or dead-lettered from the front of the queue
>   to make room for new messages once the limit is reached.

So you can pick dead-lettered messages and process them somehow or just not using max-length on queue.

Comment: Thanks! But it still not clear for me. What happen with that dropped packets.
I will read about making a queue for dead-lettered messages.

Comment: In standard case they are gone. If dead lettering or alternate exchange set up then they are published according to their rules. Read official doc on [Dead Letter Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and [Alternate Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

A dropped message is .... dropped. It disappears. Unless you have setup a dead letter rule where dropped messages will be put.